# testing controller create action in a polymorphic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic association for vote model called voteable. This's it's controller:

```ruby
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    begin
      @voteable = get_voteable
      @rating = Rating.find(params[:rating_id])
      @user = current_user
      @vote = Vote.new()
      @vote.voteable = @voteable
      @vote.rating = @rating
      @vote.user = @user
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      redirect_to stories_path, flash:{error: t('controllers.votes.create.flash.error')}
      return
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vote.save
        format.html { redirect_to story_path(@voteable), notice: t('controllers.votes.create.flash.success') }
      end
    end
  end

private
  def get_voteable
    @voteable = params[:voteable].classify.constantize.find(voteable_id)
  end

  def voteable_id
    params[(params[:voteable].singularize + "_id").to_sym]
  end
end
```

Routing is like this:

```ruby
resources :stories do
  resources :votes, :defaults => { :voteable => 'stories' }
end
```

Here is the test for controller:

```ruby
before do
  @story = FactoryGirl.create(:story)
  @rating = FactoryGirl.create(:rating)
end

it 'creates vote' do
  post :create, story_id: @story.id, rating_id: @rating
  flash[:notice].should eq(I18n.t('controllers.votes.create.flash.success'))
end
```

The test fails:

```ruby
Failure/Error: post :create, story_id: @story.id, rating_id: @rating
ActionController::RoutingError:
  No route matches {:story_id=>"1", :rating_id=>"1", :controller=
>"votes", :action=>"create"}
```

Can anyone explain me how should I use `post` here in tests?
And I have to mention that everything is working alright on production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrote the test like this and it passed:

```
it 'lets all users to create vote', focus: true do
  post :create, story_id: @story, rating_id: @rating, voteable: "stories"
  flash[:notice].should eq(I18n.t('controllers.votes.create.flash.success'))
end
```